# property frameOrigin not found on object of type UILabel

Tags: ios

I'm new into ios programming so this is probably a common misuse of techniques.

Inside my view controller I use the following code:

```
[timeLabel setTextColor:textColor];
[timeLabel setText:[NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:_reservation.date dateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle]];
[timeLabel sizeToFit];
[timeLabel setFrameOrigin:CGPointMake(61, 23)];
```

where timeLabel is declared in header file as

```
 UILabel *timeLabel;
```

along with other constants (textColor etc)

I get the following error:

```
Property frameOrigin not found on object of type UILabel
```

What am I missing? Do I need to append another frame onto each of labels (I am going to use the labels and pictograms in an UIButton view inside a table cell).

Thank you for help in advance!

Comment: frameOrigin is a property of NSView not of UIView.                 And NSView is for mac not for ios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
[timeLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(61,23,timeLabel.frame.size.width,timeLabel.frame.size.height)];
```

Or

```
CGRect frame=timeLabel.frame;
frame.origin=CGPointMake(61,23);
timeLabel.frame=frame;
```